# What does "would like to have + v3" mean?

Tags: meaning, verb-usage

1. I would like to have them removed but the process is a little confusing.
2. I would like to have it deleted, but do not know the procedure.
3. I would like to have saved it, obviously, but the game was on the line.

I saw these sentences on "ludwig" Web but don’t know the uses and meaning. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different constructions here.

The first two use the pattern *have [something] [done]*, meaning "cause something to be done", usually for one's own benefit.

So the first means something like *I would like to arrange for somebody to remove them ...*, and the second means something like  *I would like to arrange that it got deleted ...* These are not counterfactual: the person is expressing a real wish, that may happen (and may not).

The third is a different construction, because there is no object after the *have*. *To have saved* is effectively a past of the infinitive *to save*. I think a more formal form of this is *I would have liked to have saved it*, expressing a counterfactual wish that I had saved it; but I'm not surprised if a speaker avoids two *have v3* in a row like that.